# How to convert a .txt to .cdf ? Needed for Matlab that won't read txt as cdf

Tags: matlab

I have a txt file that contains data in Common Data Format( CDF ).
Matlab has functions to read this but it does not work. I assume because the extension is .txt and not .cdf.
When I try to read it I get:

??? Error using ==> cdfinfoc
Error issued from CDF library:  "NOT_A_CDF_OR_NOT_SUPPORTED: Named CDF is corrupted or
not supported by the current library version."

Error in ==> cdfinfo at 170
tmp = cdfinfoc(filename);

Error in ==> cdfread at 184
info = cdfinfo(filename);

Is there a way to trick Matlab and read it or do I need to transform somehow the txt into a .cdf? If so, how do I do that?

Thank you!

EDIT: The file that I am trying to read is from this link: http://www.ee.washington.edu/research/pstca/pf14/ieee14cdf.txt

This says that the data is in CDF: http://www.ee.washington.edu/research/pstca/pf14/pg_tca14bus.htm

Answer (score 1):

If it's actually a txt file (in that it contains textual data that you can read), then it isn't really in CDF format. You can try [makeCDF](http://spdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/makecdf.html) or some other tool to convert the textual data into a CDF file.

If that doesn't work out for you, you'll need to post more information about the actual format of the file. That text file could contain anything. Maybe provide some example lines?

**EDIT**

After looking at your file, this is an unrelated format which happens to also be called CDF. You can find a reader for this format here: [Read IEEE Common Data Format (CDF) (Power systems, Load Flow)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43519-read-ieee-common-data-format-cdf-power-systems-load-flow)

Comment: This is the file that I am trying to read as CDF: http://www.ee.washington.edu/research/pstca/pf14/ieee14cdf.txt

Comment: @PaulBajan Updated answer after looking at your file.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases I think where it's actually falling over is this call to the library:

```
fmt = cdflib.getFormat(cdfid);
```

See: [cdflib.getFormat](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cdflib.getformat.html), in particular these lines:

> This function corresponds to the CDF library C API routine
>   CDFgetFormat.
>
> To use this function, you must be familiar with the CDF C interface.
>   Read the CDF documentation at the [CDF Web site](http://cdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/).

At any rate it's not due to the file extension alone; I tested this by making a copy of the MATLAB `example.cdf`, renaming it to `example.txt`, and calling `cdfinfo` on both. No errors, returned data is the same except for obvious things like filename/modification date.

Comment: This is the file that I am trying to read in Matlab( first link from the three ones ): http://www.ee.washington.edu/research/pstca/pf14/pg_tca14bus.htm

Comment: Also, I tried to find and download the example.cdf from matlab but can't find it anywhere as a file. They mention it when they talk about the functions only.

Comment: `example.cdf` should be on your MATLAB path already; there are various `example.*` files included.  The file you link is not a `*.cdf` of the type read by the MATLAB functions - see kwatford's answer.